# Tiebreaker Question

Tags: clash-of-clans

We are in a war.  15v15. We are both going to have 41 Stars.  We have 2 stars on 1-4 and 3 on the rest. They are ahead in overall percentage.

My question is - Do we just need to get one star and improve the % destoryed or does it have to be a two star plus more % destoryed?

Answer (score 9):

> At the end of Battle Day, the winner is the clan with the most stars
>   scored against the enemy. In the case that both clans score the same
>   amount of stars, the winning clan is the clan that has dealt the
>   higher amount of total destruction. Should both clans deal the same
>   amount of stars and total destruction, the war will be considered a
>   draw. This, however can be considered rare, as total destruction dealt
>   is different in each attack and hardly sync with the enemy clan.

[source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars)

so if you get more stars than them you win. if you cannot get more stars, and you have the same amount as them, your best bet is to try and get more damage on a base in order to get a higher total damage. However, you need to have your attack be the new best attack for your total damage % to go up. Getting higher destruction % on a base, but less stars will not increase the total damage %. This is a trend I have noticed over several wars.

Comment: I get that.  We both have 41 stars.  I still have an attack left. I need to improve upon one of the bases destruction percentage.  What I am asking is do I still have to get the two stars for it to count or can I just go after percentage.

Comment: you have to get the same amount of stars plus more damage for it to count, as your new attack has to be the best attack for it to change the damage percentage. im about almost positive this is true, looking for a source to confirm

Comment: no problem. https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/3lc61j/warmy_attempt_at_delving_into_the_math_behind_the/ this link might help, and all info i can find alludes to it having to be the best attack that counts towards the total damage percentage.